# Java BufferedImage increase width

Tags: java

I have managed to load in an image using:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(out);
```

and place text over it however, I want the text to appear next to the image. How can I increase the image width on the right to allow for space for the text to be drawn on. Or do I have to create a new empty image and insert the existing one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a new buffered image and draw your existing image on top of your new larger image.